# Change the title of the theme page in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, javascript, liferay, liferay-6, page-title

I have created a theme in liferay 6.1. Now my question is how do I change the title of the theme pages.
For ex: About us page has title "**Aboutus -liferay**", I want to change it to "**Aboutus**".

I have tried using javascript for this like:
**document.title="aboutus";**

But until the page loads it shows the default title(Aboutus-liferay) and then after page load this "aboutus" title appears.

I want the custom title.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added:

```
**<head>
    <title>$the_title</title>
 </head>**
```

in my portal_normal.vm file and this solved my problem. Now whatever title i add in my html title of the pages in **Manage Pages --> pages** gets displayed in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the title inside `portal_normal.vm` of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

In `portal_normal.vm`, which is a velocity file, add your title to the following code snippet :

```
<head>
    <title>your_title</title>
</head>
```

**EDIT**

If you are talking about JSP pages, you can use:

```
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.setPageTitle(String, title, HttpServletRequest request);
```

in the respective page body.

Comment: @GarthHuff `portal_normal.vm` is inside the theme. Usually multiple pages will be assigned to a single theme. If not, you'll have to do this for all the themes you have installed. Definitely not for all the pages.

Comment: Ya you are absoultly correct. I have added the correct syntax to be added in the portal_normal.vm. Thanks for your help.